# Auto play dynamic carousel

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

What seems like a simple problem turns out to be a bit more complicated.

I have a database that contains the URL of images. I want to create a system that gets the URL and displays the image. After x seconds, download the next image and so on.

What I found:
Most dynamic carousels download all images and display them one by one.

Is it even possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have all the links then the images will be automatically displayed and you don't have to download images to show them. And if you want to download all of them then you can just loop through the array containing them and download it . Here is the solution to that in nodejs.

```js
var fs = require('fs'),
    request = require('request');

var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
    console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);

    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
  });
};

download('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png', 'google.png', function(){
  console.log('done');
});
```

Comment: Downloading is indeed not needed.
What I meant by download was the browser has to download the image.
I have no idea how to auto refresh and get the following image with the URL in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Started all over from scratch and fixed it with a simple tag.

Bootstrap 5.1 carousel and the HTML tag `<img src="..." loading="lazy">`